# Is the Brazil Nut Effect quantitative?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, entropy, granulated-materials

The [Brazil Nut Effect (a.k.a. granular convection)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granular_convection) has a straightforward statistical mechanical interpretation as a system minimizing its free energy, at least qualitatively.  What I wonder is **whether there are any known quantitative relationships describing this effect?**

For example, is there some sort of effective temperature?  Is there a way of approximating the entropy of the system?  Is there a way to estimate the probability that a nut of a given size will be found at a given height in a container?  Wikipedia mentions no such relationships, but I'm sure people have thought about this.

Comment: I've found a paper on this behind a paywall. [Here](https://sci-hub.tf/https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.79.829) is a sci-hub.tf link to the PDF, which may rot as sci-hub proxies keep changing. [Here](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=granular+convection+model&pws=0) you'll find a few other studies, mostly numerical.

Comment: The depth probability of a given nut is directly proportional to your desire to eat said nut  :-)